# linear operators on infinite dimensional spaces are not necessarily bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $v=C([0,1])$ be the vector space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to R$ with norm given by $$ \||f\||=\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt$$ Let $T:V\to R$ given by $T(f)=f(0)$.
Show that T is not bounded.

I had two ways to approach this problem, but they contradict with each other.

First method: Since V is infinite dimensional, we know that T is not compact. Then if $(f_1,f_2,...)$ with $\||f_i\||=1$ is a sequence in V, then $(Tf_1,Tf_2,...)$ does not have a cluster point,so no subsequence of  $(Tf_1,Tf_2,...)$ converges. So the sequence goes to infinity.

Second method: $\frac{\||Tf\||}{\||f\||}=\frac{|f(0)|}{\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt}\le 1 $ since $|f(0)| \le \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt$. Actually it turns out that T is bounded.

Also,I'm wondering if T is not bounded on all infinite dimensional spaces?

Can anyone see what my problem is? Thanks in advance

Comment: $|f(0)| \leq \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt$ is certainly not true. Think of a function which starts off very tall, but goes to 0 very quickly.

Comment: Sorry I still can't see the problem here. I am thinking that $|f(0)|$ is contained in the integral so this "less or equal" relation must hold.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with general $f_n$ you need to write down an actual sequence. Try this one $$f_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{n}}}.$$
This example also directly contradicts your reasoning in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function

$$ f_n(t) = \begin{cases} n^2\left(\frac{1}{n} - t\right) & \text{for } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The graph of $f_n$ looks like a triangle, and it's easy to see that it has area $\frac{1}{2}$. But $f_n(0) = n$, so we have a sequence of functions such that $Tf_n$ has norm $n$, but $f_n$ has norm $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Or try the sequence $f_n(x) = (1-x)^n$. The norm is $\frac{1}{n}$, while $T(f_n)= 1$.